# Три оси в градусах в 3Д вектор

Tags: python, матрицы, vector, 3d

Недавно я решил написать свой RTX движок в реальном времени используя Python. Цель была в том чтобы проверить на что способен питон (Это не есть производительный язык) и достичь хотябы 5 кадров в секунду. Когда я взялся за 3Д матрицу, я столкнулся с трудностю, как превратить 3 оси (в градусах в 3Д вектор) Тоесть чтобы (0 0 90) вернуло (0 0 1). 0 0 90 Это градусы поворота, а 0 0 1 результат. (Вектор направления)

Кода у меня нету, нашёл лишь в интернете функцию превращения 2 осей в 2Д вектор. Но движок который я делаю 3д. Помогите пожалуста!

Comment: Что такое `0 0 90` ???

Comment: Это три значения осей (градусы 3д поворота) (матрица)

Comment: Я не понимаю этой фразы. Если подразумевается поворот вокруг OX, OY, OZ на 0 ,0,90 градусов, то каков порядок поворота и каков начальный вектор?